# Fabric.js: Problem while resizing the rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Code: https://codepen.io/eajithkumar128/pen/poNwJJv?editors=0010

I have a table like structure in the canvas drawn using a rectangle, I have drawn lines in the row and column ends like below (lines in blue color are rectangle and red color lines are the fabric line object)

[image]

I am trying to adjust the size of the rectangles by moving the lines, whenever I am moving the column lines I could see the entire rectangle itself moving wherein I am only trying to update the width, Also I could see an imaginary rectangle drawn behind it which has correct width, but the original rectangle is not resizing correctly. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

Code to get the rect object before and after lines while selecting the line:

```
canvas.on('selection:created', function(e){
        let targetEle = e.target;
    initialPosition = e.left;
    selectedBoxesLeft = []
        selectedBoxesRight = []
    canvas.forEachObject((v)=>{
        if(v.left+v.width === targetEle.left && v.type==="rect"){
        selectedBoxesLeft.push(v);
      }
      if(v.left === targetEle.left && v.type==="rect"){
        selectedBoxesRight.push(v);
      }
    });
    console.log(selectedBoxesLeft);
    console.log(selectedBoxesRight);
});
```

Code to resize while moving:

```
canvas.on('object:moving',function(e){
    let target = e.target;
  if(target.left < initialPosition){
    selectedBoxesLeft.forEach((v)=>{
      v.width =target.left - v.left
    })
    
    selectedBoxesRight.forEach((v)=>{
      let left = v.left
      v.left = target.left;
      v.width = v.width + (left- target.left)
    });
    canvas.renderAll()
  }else{
    // selectedBoxesLeft.forEach((v)=>{
    //   v.width = v.width + (target.left - v.width)
    // })
    // selectedBoxesRight.forEach((v)=>{
    //   // v.width = v.width + (v.left - target.left)
    //   v.left = target.left;
    //   v.width = v.width - target.left;
    // })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While Resizing the rectangle instead of using

```
v.width =target.left - v.left
```

changed it to

```
v.set('width', target.left - v.left)
```

resolved the issue